# looping through try with different variables

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, try-catch

I'm collecting company data from accident reports
How can I loop the trys and excepts into one for-loop or something better using different variables from the list?

I just want to simplify this.

```
name = company_location
for i, j in enumerate (list):
    if j == 'Last 10 Accidents':
        last = i
        try:
            date1 = list[last+28]
            employee1 = list[last+31]
            days_lost1 = list[last+49]
            days_paid1 = list[last+43]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(str(name)+", "+str(date1)+", "+str(employee1)+", "+str(days_lost1)+", "+str(days_paid1))
            report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(str(name)+"\n")
            report.close()

        try:
            date2 = list[last+50]
            employee2 = list[last+53]
            days_lost2 = list[last+71]
            days_paid2 = list[last+65]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(", "+str(date2)+", "+str(employee2)+", "+str(days_lost2)+", "+str(days_paid2))
            report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write("\n")
            report.close()

        try:
            date3 = list[last+72]
            employee3 = list[last+75]
            days_lost3 = list[last+93]
            days_paid3 = list[last+87]
            with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
                report.write(", "+str(date3)+", "+str(employee3)+", "+str(days_lost3)+", "+str(days_paid3))
        report.close()
        except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
        with open("report.csv","a+") as report:
        report.write("\n")
report.close()
```

Comment: Maybe this is a question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seeing as your code already works.

Comment: Thank you K. Menyah.  I just posted it there.